# use pre-populated realm databse

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I want to create an offline iOS application using Realm. Users just need to read the database, they don't need to update or create entries.

I can create my pre-populated database using `Realm Studio` and I need to use that database file in my final app so users can access the database with the same data. For example, `jobs.realm` file with same data should be available to the users when they first launch the app.

I've been searching for a solution but couldn't find anything I can understand.

Comment: This is generally done through a bundled realm as mentioned in the answer. You have a number of other options as well including bundling a text file or plist in your project and then crafting a local realm from that data on app start. Without a description of the specific issues you don't understand, it will be difficult to provide any kind of concrete answer. Can you update and clarify your question describing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation for bundling a realm file: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm

Comment: i've seen this one already. but couldn't understand it.